# Column with different data types in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I would need your support if possible..

Currently within my dataset there is a table "SUM" like below, where columns "Jan" and "Feb" contains both decimal and whole numbers data types.

Is it possible to convert some of the whole number to currency and some other to decimal with 2 decimal places ?

SUM TABLE

---

| title | Jan | Feb |
| --- | --- | --- |
| New users | 80 | 90 |
| users | 200 | 150 |
| BV | 74562.62 | 82617.93 |
| Charge | 0.063629 | 0.061740 |
| ______________________________________ |  |  |

desired output

---

| title | Jan | Feb |
| --- | --- | --- |
| New users | 80 | 90 |
| users | 200 | 150 |
| BV | $745,626 | $826,179 |
| Charge | 0.06 | 0.06 |
| ______________________________________ |  |  |

I think that in Power BI a column has only one data type.

Is there any way to achieve the desired output?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to re-structure your data. In a proper data model, there is no such thing as different data types in the same column. The answers that suggest to use DAX to address the problem will take you in a very wrong direction. Power BI requires a proper star schema: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_schema

Answer (score 1):

It would be best to structure your data, into a format that it can be used for example, change data types and creating measures.

In this example, using the query editor, you need to first Unpivot your Jan/Feb columns from columns to rows

[image: Original Data]

With unpivot it becomes this:

[image: Unpivoted]

You then need to Pivot your data on the Title, select the column 'Title' Pivot on the Values column created in the previous step

[image: Final data]

This now allows you to correct your formatting, create measures, and also map by month better, without the need for complicated DAX formatting when creating measures

Answer (score 0):

To display several data type within a column, you need add new measure for each month you prepare to display and accept the answer if helping :)

Here is the dax formula for `Jan`, you may need calcuate for `Feb` if necessary:

```
Measure = IF(SELECTEDVALUE(Sheet1[title])="BV",FORMAT(SUM(Sheet1[Jan]),"Currency"),
             IF(SELECTEDVALUE(Sheet1[title])="Charge",FIXED(SUM(Sheet1[Jan]),2),
                   FORMAT(SUM(Sheet1[Jan]),"General Number")))
```

[image]

By display the `measure` on the table, you will have the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To display different data types in a table, you can create a measure with the following DAX for the `Feb` column, you can do the same for other columns too.

```
    Measure = 
    VAR VAL = SUMMARIZE('Table','Table'[Feb])
    RETURN SWITCH( SELECTEDVALUE('Table'[Title]), 
                 "Users", FORMAT(VAL, "0"),
                 "BV", FORMAT(VAL, "$0"),
                 "Charge", FORMAT(VAL, "0.00"),
                 "New Users", FORMAT(VAL , "0")
                )
```

[image: Output]

Comment: This solution worked for me. However, having a larger number of data (e.g. "New Charge", "New BV" etc) in column "title", results in some data (e.g.  "New BV") not being displayed (appear with blanks). I checked my code and it is correct without errors. Im looking for it but i can not find out what happening.

Comment: Can you post your code here? It may be due to some incorrect data type implementation. Happened to me with `Charge` in the Title column, so I checked and made sure that it's the correct data type.

Comment: Ok here is my code: Measure = VAR VAL = SUMMARIZE ('SUM','SUM'[Jan]) RETURN SWITCH( SELECTEDVALUE('SUM'[title]), "BV", FORMAT(VAL,"$0"), "Charge", FORMAT(VAL,"0.00"), "New Users", FORMAT(VAL,"0"), "Users", FORMAT(VAL,"0"), "New BV", FORMAT(VAL,"$0"), "New Charge", FORMAT(VAL,"0.00"))